# Notification when a new version is available?

Tags: webapp-rec

Is there a web site which notifies you with email when a new version of an app is available (for apps like Winrar, Google Earth, phpBB, MediaWiki, Wordpress, Firefox)?

Comment: Might be a bit unrelated, but I know that at least Wordpress and Firefox does that themselves, whenever you use them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[FileHippo.com](http://filehippo.com/) will accomplish something similar that what you want to do (but it doesn't email you or anything). If you install the [FileHippo.com Update Checker](http://filehippo.com/updatechecker/) it will scan and notify you of updates (there is an option to be notified of beta updates as well).

Answer (score 0):

Similar to FileHippo, but slightly different (Focus is more on Windows Drivers, but also works for some programs):

- [**RadarSync**](http://www.radarsync.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I realize that there has been one year since you asked this question, however, if this is still of interest to you I thought you might be interested in this.

We developed a tool meant to help users achieve just that - notify you when there is a newer version for one of the applications you have installed on your Windows computer - and it's called Soft32 Updater.

You can find out more about this tool at http://updater.soft32.com